# Form To Redirect To A Page, Based On Data Entered

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

This is probably super amateur but I'm having a brain fart.

I want to place a form field on a page that redirects to a specific page, based on the data entered in to the field. For example, if a user enters dave and hits submit, they will be redirected to dave.html... if the user enters 1234, they will be redirected to 1234.html.

I'm using sky-forms, and as far as I know this could be as simple as adding an if function to the script... any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="cforms">
    <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
function redirect(){
var target = $('#mainText').val();
var redirectTo = 'http://' + target + '.html';
window.location.replace(redirectTo);
}


 </script>
    <form onsubmit="redirect()" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <section class="col col-4">
            <label class="label">Enter Quote Number</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-file"></i>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </label>
          </section>
     </div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in html only, you need at least javascript or a server side language like PHP to take the form field and do the redirect.

Comment: Honestly, My mind is spinning and I'm not sure where to even start. :(

Comment: I have some javascript for form validation and know how to build php for submitting forms to my email but have no idea how to just have the form redirect based on entered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use javascript
something like this should work

```js
function redirect(){
  var target = $('#mainText').val();
  var redirectTo = 'http://' + target + '.html';
  window.location.replace(redirectTo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="redirect()">
          Enter name: <input id="mainText" type="text">
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks. I'll let you know how this goes.

Comment: Question... let's assume I want to redirect to cars.html on my site, where would the edits go in the code above?

Comment: in the js function it would look somehing like that:
...
var redirectTo = 'ht tp://mysite/' +target+'.html';
...
...

Comment: it's not letting me vote up... says it requires a 15 reputation.

Comment: On a side note... I'm still stuck, the form doesn't seem to be redirecting.

Comment: can you post your script please?

Comment: Ok, as you can see... The jquery get its value from #mainText, but the id of your input is 'name',  so change adjust the jquery line to it and give it another try

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. The result I'm getting is just an update to the web address to http://nurelo.com/quote?name=test

Comment: I have var target = $('#name').val();
  var redirectTo = 'http://nurelo.com/' + target + '.html';